# Get row from ansible stout

Tags: ansible

I want set variable from my stdout. 
I use in my task

```
  register: output_dhcp
  when: not static_ip

- set_fact:
    vmid: "{{ output_dhcp.results }}"
```

and get next stdout

```
changed: [127.0.0.1] => (item=delete-after-tests) => {
    "changed": true, 
    "invocation": {
        "module_args": {
            "api_host": "192.168.0.203", 
            "api_password": "VALUE_SPECIFIED_IN_NO_LOG_PARAMETER", 
            "api_user": "root@pam", 
            "nameserver": null, 
            "netif": {
                "net0": "name=eth0,ip=dhcp,ip6=dhcp,bridge=vmbr0"
            }, 
            "node": "pve3", 
            "vmid": null
        }
    }, 
    "item": "delete-after-tests", 
    "msg": "deployed VM 108 from template local:vztmpl/ubuntu-18.04-standard_18.04.1-1_amd64.tar.gz"
}
```

Me need get number id  - 108 . I can't get row

```
"msg": "deployed VM 108 from template local:vztmpl/ubuntu-18.04-standard_18.04.1-1_amd64.tar.gz"
```

for parsing, without other rows.

```
- set_fact:
    vmid: "{{ output_dhcp.results.msg }}"
```

doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

The fact that you have `(item=delete-after-tests)` in your output means you have cheated us by not including the `with_items:` that is almost certainly hiding above your `register: output_dhcp` line.

When you have a `with_` statement, it packages the actual output underneath a `results` list, which you kind of hinted at with your `output_dhcp.results.msg` but you cannot ask for a field `.msg` of a `list`; you need to extract the attribute of each member of the list, which `map` will do for you:

```
- debug:
    msg: '{{ output_dhcp.results | map(attribute="msg") | list }}'
```

But if you want the `108` of the expression `VM 108` then you'll need to use `regex_replace` to extract it, but presumably only on the list items that could possibly match it, like so:

```
- debug:
    msg: >-
     {{ output_dhcp.results 
      | selectattr("msg", "match", "VM [0-9]+ .*")
      | map("regex_replace", ".*VM ([0-9]+) .*", "\\1")
      | first }}
```

Comment: Hi! First debug return me fine result with required result from "msg". But secondary debug returned error:
`
The task includes an option with an undefined variable. The error was: No first item, sequence was empty
` 
Below is row from debug:
`
  "msg": "deployed VM 109 from template local:vztmpl/ubuntu-18.04-standard_18.04.1-1_amd64.tar.gz"

`